# How to Set Up Apache to Run Two Applications

Tags: php, apache

I have a a URL www.example.com that runs a WordPress site...and I also have www.example.com/faq that runs a laravel app.  I am having issues with setting up apache to recognze the www.example.com/faq.  I keep getting 404 errors as it's using www.example.com to find the faq document.

I am using Apache 2.4.6

Here is how I have my Apache Conf file set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com
        Alias example.com/faq "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/faq"

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log forwarded
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Your WordPress site and its .htaccess file specifically are probably getting in the way of running the Laravel site in a subfolder. Create a seperate Virtual host for the Laravel site

Comment: no issues in apache server, may issue laravel config base path or in index file of laravel app

Answer (score 0):

you shoud create two virtual host for both two URl

Comment: And this should have been a comment